# Parsing comment levels from forum posts

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Is it possible to find out the comment levels from this web like below?
https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/249439#comment-3719026

From jsoup I am able to parse the comments, username etc, but I am having trouble getting the correct comment levels.

Viewing the source of that page, the  doesn't match with the correct live posts, unless I am reading it all wrong.

Is there a way to solve this?

I was able to generate the source comment level using:

```
        String url = "https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/249439";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements level = doc.select("ul.comment");


         for(Element column : e.select("ul")){
                //comment level
                System.out.println(column.attr("class"));
                levels.add(column.attr("class"));
            }
```

But its doesn't look right. Only showing 1 of level 0 comment etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for(Element column : e.select("ul")) {
>     //comment level
>     System.out.println(column.attr("class"));
>     levels.add(column.attr("class"));
> }
> ```

From the above code where does the `e` comes from?

Anyway, you need to parse the class attribute value in order to find the comment level.

Here is a working sample code:

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url="https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/249439#comment-3719026";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements comments = doc.select("div.comment-wrap");

    Matcher levelMatcher = Pattern.compile("(?i)^(.*level)(\\d+)(.*)$").matcher("");
    List<String> levels = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Comments found: "+ comments.size());

    for (Element comment : comments) {            
        if (levelMatcher.reset(comment.parent().parent().className()).find()) {
            levels.add(levelMatcher.replaceAll("$2"));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(levels);
}
```

#### OUTPUT [https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/249439#comment-3719026] *(may change depending on the request time)*

```
Comments found: 38
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

#### OUTPUT [https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/249604] *(may change depending on the request time)*

```
Comments found: 14
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: oh wow that's the first time I've come across the Matcher class. It seems like an excellent way to filter out all unnecessary info which I what I keep ending up with. Thanks man, although it does look a bit confusing, I'll try follow this design pattern for the next problems.

Comment: I just had a look at it again, and there seems to be another problem. In the source, after the first comment (level 0), it doesn't show any further levels 0's (new comments, not replies). Not sure how I would do this as there is no 'class' shown, only  </div></li></ul></li><li>

Comment: @Petersicecream There is only one level0. `ul.level0` holds all comments and replies made to the offer.

Comment: Yep, it shows the first level0, but for some reason the source stops showing future level0's and have that part blank. For example, [link](https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/249604) there's 8 comments, and suppose to be 5 level 0's and 3 level1's. But looking at the source, its [0,1,1,1]. So its missing the 0's in between. Solution is suppose to be [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]. Thanks, I hope you understand.

Comment: @Petersicecream Please see my update. Don't hesitate to post new test case.

Comment: This is perfect!. I'll use this as a guide to retrieve further data. Thanks Stephan.